# can you collect social security if you're over 70 and are employed?

Tags: united-states, social-security

My father is about to turn 70 and he's employed. He has the option to continue working but it's unclear to either of us if he'll be able to collect social security while he has his job?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

He will be able to collect the full amount. From [the Social Security website](https://www.ssa.gov/pubs/EN-05-10069.pdf), emphasis added:

> If you were born January 2, 1943, 
>   through January 1, 1955,
>    , then your 
>   full retirement age for retirement 
>   insurance benefits is 66. 
>   **If you work, 
>   and are full retirement age or older, you 
>   may keep all of your benefits, no matter 
>   how much you earn.**
>    If you’re younger 
>   than full retirement age, there is a limit 
>   to how much you can earn and still 
>   receive full Social Security benefits. If 
>   you’re younger than full retirement age 
>   during all of 2015, we must deduct $1 
>   from your benefits for each $2 you earn 
>   above $15,720.
>   If you reach full retirement age 
>   during 2015,
>    we must deduct $1 from 
>   your benefits for each $3 you earn above 
>   $41,880 until the month you reach full 
>   retirement age.

Comment: Definitely confirmed.  I know someone that's over 70, still working part time and collecting their full benefit.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that he was eligible to collect the full social security benefits for 4 years already while at work?

Comment: @Peteris If he had started four years ago, he would have got less per month. Benefits increase with age at which one starts until 70. (https://faq.ssa.gov/link/portal/34011/34019/Article/3735/What-is-the-maximum-Social-Security-retirement-benefit-payable)